# Matthews/Phi Coefficient on a 2x2 Contingency Table with Rare Positives

Tags: correlation, descriptive-statistics, contingency-tables, confusion-matrix, adjustment

Suppose I want to measure the degree people like gold versus silver. For the sake of argument, let's say I have a contingency table like so:

```
          Gold Silver
Like         5      0
Dislike      9     11
```

This would yield a phi coefficient of 0.4432, indicating a "moderate" preference for gold.

Now suppose I cannot measure likes or dislikes directly. Instead, I can only watch how a potential customer acts when presented with either a gold or silver item. I observe 200 customers and record their actions when randomly presented with either a gold or silver item:

```
          Gold Silver
Buy         20      2
Don't Buy   80     98
```

This would yield a phi coefficient of 0.28764, indicating a "weak" preference for gold.

So, here, the act of buying is rare. Or, in other words, there are a lot of window shoppers who don't buy because they cannot afford the item even though they like it.

I've thought of "correcting" the counts in the table based on the probability of being a buyer. That is, P(Buy) = 22/200, so 80*(1-P(Buy)) = 71.2 window shoppers and 8.8 real dislikers of gold. Doing that gives a contingency table like so:

```
          Gold Silver
Like      20.0    2.0
Dislike    8.8   10.8
```

This yields a phi coefficient of 0.4976, pushing the correlation back into the "moderate" range.

My concern is that the table no longer contains observations but predictions. Further, I've not seen any work on how to appropriately adjust 2x2 contingency tables in this kind of scenario. Does anyone have some insights here? Is what I'm doing completely off-base? Is there any literature out there pointing to a better way to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have an answer to my question.

[Zysno (1997)](https://www.dgps.de/fachgruppen/methoden/mpr-online/issue2/art5/article.html) sets forth the following scenario:

"As an example, a fictitious examination of the association between sex and subscription of a woman's journal can be used, where by a correlation of $\phi = .50$ may have been found. It might be
concluded that, although this magazine is more often read by women, it is also read by men. Without access to the original data there is little reason to distrust this interpretation. However a more precise inspection of the data would reveal that the sample of 1000 individuals was made up on the one hand of 500 female and 500 male subjects, and on the other hand of 800 non-subscribers and 200 exclusively female subscribers. (The cells of the fourfold table might contain the following frequencies: $a=200, b=300, c=0, d=500$). Actually a very strong association between sex and magazine subscription is given: The subscribers are exclusively female, male subjects do not take the journal. This fact should be expressed by a $\phi^* = 1$, but the Phi-coefficient fails to do so."

He then goes on to construct $\phi^*$, which he calls a Phi-modification.

I've written an R script that implements both the Phi-coefficient and Zysno's Phi-modification.

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

if (length(args) != 4) {
  stop(paste("Please supply a b c d"), call.=FALSE)
}

a <- as.integer(args[1])
b <- as.integer(args[2])
c <- as.integer(args[3])
d <- as.integer(args[4])

phi <- (a*d - b*c)/sqrt((a + b)*(c + d)*(a + c)*(b + d))

N <- a + b + c + d
e <- ifelse(a*d >= b*c, min(b ,c), min(a, d))

phi_star <- (a*d - b*c)/(abs(a*d - b*c) + N*e)

writeLines(paste("Phi-coefficient: ", round(phi, digits=4)))
writeLines(paste("Phi-modification: ", round(phi_star, digits=4)))
```

Running the script on the middle example in the question yields:

```
$ ./correlation.R 20 2 80 98
Phi-coefficient:  0.2876
Phi-modification:  0.8182
```

So, the Phi-modification attains a value indicating a "very strong" preference for gold. That is the desired outcome, and it arises because the modification acknowledges that "a symmetric partition of two sets of events will … be the exception in natural binary variables."

**EDIT**

Based on the advice of a statistics professor, I've decided to go with a cosine-pi approximation of the tetrachoric correlation coefficient ([Bouvier, Perry, Michael, & Hertzka, 1954](https://doi.org/10.1177/001316445401400413)).

For the sake of completeness, that gives:

```
$ ./correlation.R 20 2 80 98
Phi-coefficient:  0.2876
Phi-modification:  0.8182
Tetrachoric:  0.766
```